# Opencv Issue while running the code on jupyter

Tags: python-3.x

error: OpenCV(4.7.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:1272: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'

error: OpenCV(4.7.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:1272: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by changing the version of opencv.I am using opencv-python==4.5.3.56.Maybe you can try.